# Is probability relative?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If I have tossed the coin 3 times. And got heads. Fourth time, the probability that head comes is 1/16. (For 4 heads in a row).
But If another person considers this to be the first toss. Probability for him is 1/2.

Comment: You seem to be affected by the [gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy)

Answer (score 4):

> If I have tossed the coin 3 times. And got heads. Fourth time, the probability that head comes is 1/16.

No.   The probability for obtaining *four heads among four* tosses is $1/16$.   That is a different event.

You want the *conditional* probability for obtaining a head on the forth toss *when given* three heads obtained among the first three tosses, which is $1/2$.

Since the individual toss results are independent, this is *also* simply the probability for obtaining a *head on the forth toss*.